# Find $a,b$ such that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}=4$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am stuck on a question. The question is the image attached. I know that in order for the limit to equal $4$, the numerator and denominator have to be $\frac{0}{0}$. I tried solving for the numerator by making it equal to $0$, but I am not sure if I am doing it right because I got stuck. Any suggestions?

> If $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}=4$, find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: No, I have not yet. My teacher wants us to do it algebraically and of course using limits

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I am new to this site.

Comment: Do you think you could still help me? I have been stuck on this problem for over 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by setting the numerator equal to $0$.

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}&=0\\
ax-b(x-3)&=0\\
ax-bx+3b&=0\\
\end{align}

then substitute $x=1$:

\begin{align}
a+2b=0 \implies a=-2b
\end{align}

substitute this back into the original limit:

\begin{align}
4&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{-2b}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{-3b(x-1)}{x(x-3)}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-3b}{x(x-3)}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}b
\end{align}

so $b=\frac{8}{3}\implies a=\frac{-16}{3}$.

Comment: Wow, it seems like I was on the right track, but somehow got stuck. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: @P1081 Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Find $a,b$ such that

$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}=4$

I would start with:

$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac{ax -b(x-3)}{(x-1)(x)(x-3)}=4\\
\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac{(a-b)x +3b}{(x-1)(x)(x-3)}=4\\$

When we evaluate the limit at $x = 1$ the factors $x(x-3) = -2$

Find $a,b$ such that:

$\frac{(a-b)x +3b}{-2(x-1)} = \frac{4(x-1)}{x-1} = 4$

or

$(a- b)x + 3b = -8x + 8\\
a-b = -8\\
3b = 8$

And that is a pretty simple system of equations to solve.

Comment: Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac a{x-3}-\frac bx=-\frac a2-b$$and that you want this to be $0$. So, take $a=-2b$. Then$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac a{x-3}-\frac bx}{x-1}=b\lim_{x\to1}\frac{-\frac2{x-3}-\frac1x}{x-1}=\frac{3b}2.$$So, take $b=\frac83$.

Comment: So would a = -16/3?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and your clarification!